# How do I send XML post requests to a website with no API?

Tags: c#, xml, http-post

I'm pretty new to networks so please excuse the ignorance. For a while now I've been happy just using XML POST requests when I needed my app to send project data to project management sites with APIs. But now I'm tasked with getting the app to work with a service that hasn't released an API yet and I'm clueless, and haven't had much luck finding resources on how to send this kind of data.

Here's a C# code example I use to send project info to a site that does have an API:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    XmlElement project = doc.CreateElement("project");
    doc.AppendChild(project);

    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "name", projectName);
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "active", true);
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "bill-by", EnumPresenter.XmlRepresentation(invoiceMethod));
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "client-id", clientID);
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "budget-by", EnumPresenter.XmlRepresentation(budget));
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "starts-on", startDate, XmlDateFormat.Harvest);
    XmlParse.CreateAddElement(project, "ends-on", endDate, XmlDateFormat.Harvest);

    var r = PostRequest("projects", doc.InnerXml);
```

How should I go about with this for a site with no API? Is it possible to make post requests at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can record the http request via `fiddler` and any other tool. After that you have to use `HttpClient` class's method like `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` according to recorded fiddler request. Hope it help.